# uitextfield problem - retrieving

Tags: xcode

I have a 3 text fields and a button. I want to press on the first uitextfield, press on the button and `hello world` to be pasted, and same goes to the others. I know how to do this, but my method is too basic and I need to keep the same pasting code .. (so I guess in a way what im asking is, how can I retrieve the uitextfield that the user presses so I can alter it)

this is what i do:

```
if ( textfield1.isEditing ) {
   textfield1.text = ...
}
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the variable `textfield1`, because if I have 1000 textfields I will have to write 1000 lines .. I can do loops but I want to retrieve the value somehow maybe using the sender? (new to xcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you implement the textFieldDidBeginEditing function:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 // process text
}
```

and set the delegate of your text fields to the viewcontroller that contains this function.  The input parameter textField should be the textfield that you are currently editing.  This way you wont have to do the 1000 lines of code you mentioned.